# Is there any event for re-focus the page of browser?

Tags: javascript, events

I left the page or browser for a while and come back to the page after a while. Is there any event for the re-focus?

Comment: Let the page to open another and then return (via Back button etc), or you left your computer open and made a cup of coffee and then returned?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can detect a blur and focus event on the window object [in most browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by coming back to page but, you can use:

```
<body onfocus="yourjsfunction();">
```

or:

```
<body onmouseover="yourjsfunction();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in all browsers, but

```
document.focus = function() {
   //stuff to do
}
```